# 9-patch background adds top and bottom padding. How to avoid it?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to customize `ToggleButton` in my app. I'm setting 9-patch image as background as written [here](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/).
And then in my layout xml:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_toggle_bg"
    android:checked="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
```

`btn_toogle_bg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/toggle"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle"/>
</layer-list>
```

`btn_toggle.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

9-patch looks like this (`btn_toggle_off`):

[image: btn_toggle_off]

The same image for checked state.

But when I'm applying this as background I get some unexpected top and bottom padding:

[image][image]

I've got the same result when applying this background to `Button` or using xml-drawable as background.
How to avoid unexpected padding? Help, please.

---

**Update:**

Also, when I'm adding this style to the app theme there is no padding but `ToggleButton` becames unclickable (doesn't change its state):

`styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Widget.Button.Toggle" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_toggle_bg</item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
</style>
```

`themes.xml`:

```
<style name="MyThemeName" parent="@android:Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/Widget.Button.Toggle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's padding or drawable and not of the view ? Try placing a colored view (instead of a text view) in a container with that drawable, to check.

Comment: @User117 I'm not sure but see update, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I needed to extend `android:Widget.Button.Toggle` style:

```
<style name="Widget.Button.Toggle" parent="android:Widget.Button.Toggle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_toggle_bg</item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the padding is your right black pixel that describes where the content should be placed, should be the whole length of the image from top to bottom.

try this:

[image]

Comment: I tried to do so, but I got the same result. Also without content lines I got the same.